# How to remove matching height of two divs javascript for small devices

Tags: jquery, css

I've two divs named "A" and "B". The height of both div isn't fixed. And I want "B" will get the same height as "A" gets. So, I put a script like this:

```
setHeight($('.a'), $('.b'));
function setHeight(elem1, elem2) {
   var height = elem1.height()
   elem2.css('height', height); 
}
```

But for small devices, I don't want the same height. So, I've put this **which is not working**:

```
$(window).on(resize, function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        setHeight($('.a'), $('.b'));  
    } else {
        elem2.css('height', 'auto');    
    }   
});
```

What's the right script for it? [My fiidle work](http://jsfiddle.net/0h8utgkb/)

Comment: `$(window).on(resize, function() {` should be `$(window).on('resize', function() {`. And what's `elem2` in the resize function?

Comment: Yup, looks like you forgot the quotes around the event type. You can often catch that sort of thing by looking at the developer console (it would probably say "`resize` is undefined)

Comment: That's really not JS's job you know? Try reading about `media queries`...

Comment: I've put quotes now. But, still no change: http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/0h8utgkb/1/ 
@j08691, I don't understand how I can put elem2 correctly inside resize function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned you are missing the `'`s around `resize` but also `elem2` is undefined in that function.

You need use a pointer to the element:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        setHeight($('.a'), $('.b'));  
    } else {
        $('.b').css('height', 'auto');  
    }   
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0h8utgkb/2/)

Also, because you don't want `setHeight()` to run on page load if the user is using a mobile device you should check the window width before calling the function:

```
if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    setHeight($('.a'), $('.b'));
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0h8utgkb/4/)

Comment: Got the problem now. Thanks